# How to run Timit recipe of Kaldi on cluster using a singularity container?

Tags: c, python-3.x, bash

I ran the Timit recipe of Kaldi on both local CPU and GPU machines and it worked well. However, we have an issue to run this recipe on our university cluster with slurm. I have looked for a solution online but couldn't find anything helpful at least in our case. I should mention that we are using a singularity container in which Kaldi has been installed. we tested the container with run.pl and it worked. We need to submit our job with slrum.pl in order to speed up the running time. I did that but get the following error. Could anyone help me to deal with this problem?

Error: /bin/bash: sbatch: command not found

Any help would be highly appreciated,